# Can't open the file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am opening a file on a project. I don't know why but, I typed a file path and it's exactly correct path, just there is something to do with the syntax or maybe it just doesn't want to open. Error occurs in open()

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
script = ""
File = "../Program/Test.dvrob"
with open(File, 'r') as program:
    script = program.read()
    print(script)
```

In c#, I can use ../ to go back, but in python, I can't, and I am having trouble researching how to do so. I also tried "../../Program/Test.dvrob" and didn't work and I am not very experienced python programmer. I need help. Thank you.

Path:
[Path Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsfDD.jpg) (Edit, not Test.py)

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Comment: Added, here you go.

Comment: Give absolute path of file and try.also change `File` to `file`

Comment: You can "go back" with `"../"` in Python as well but the path is relative to the current working directory which may not be what you expect. Try `print(os.getcwd())` to find out.

Comment: any error messages about your code?

Comment: Error occures in Open()

Comment: Which error (show as properly formatted text in the question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you can't use an absolute path?

If not, you could use `__file__`, should you be inside a module. This should give you the path your file is under, although I believe it's not guaranteed. Then you can do something like

```
from pathlib import Path
path = (Path(__file__) / "../path/to/thing").resolve()
```

Or, instead of `__file__` you can use `pathlib.Path.cwd()` to get the current working directory and then do the same as above.

Comment: Thank you, I am not very experienced programmer, but it definitely resolved my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    script = ""
    File = "../123.txt"
    with open(File, 'r') as program:
        script = program.read()
        print(script)
```

I tested the code with python3.5, no error.

Answer (score 0):

From your image, your file name is `Test.py` not `Test.dvrob`

Comment: Test.py was a temporary name, and I changed to dvrob. Sorry for confusion.